# Integral convergence involving Lp and Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Quick question, any contribution or hint would be appreciated:

How does it follow that:

$$\lim\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty}\int_{\Omega}a(u_{k})\frac{\partial u_{k}}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \int_{\Omega}b(u_{k})\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \int_{\Omega}a(u)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \int_{\Omega}b(u)\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

Where $v \in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ and $u_{k} \rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{1,2}(\Omega) \Subset L^{2-\epsilon}(\Omega)$, so it follows that $u_{k} \rightarrow u$ in $L^{2-\epsilon}(\Omega)$ where $\epsilon > 0$. Also $a(u_{k}) \rightarrow a(u)$ in $L^{2}(\Omega)$ and $b(u_{k}) \rightarrow b(u)$ in $L^{1}(\Omega)$.

$\Omega$ is given as a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w=\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}$. Since $v\in W^{1,\infty}$, we have $w\in L^\infty$. The space $L^\infty$ is dual to $L^1$. Thus, pairing a fixed $L^\infty$ function with a convergent sequence of $L^1$ functions produces a convergent sequence of numbers. This is why 
$$\int b(u_k) w\to \int b(u)w$$

For the other integral, note that  $a(u_k)w$ converges in $L^2$, since multiplication by a bounded function is a continuous operator. Then use the following

**General fact**: if $f_k \rightharpoonup f$ in $L^p$ and $g_k\to g$ in $L^q$, where $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$, then $\int f_kg_k\to \int fg $. Reason: 
$$f_kg_k - fg = (f_k - f)g+f_k(g_k - g)$$
 where the integral of the first term goes to zero by the definition of weak convergence, and the second by  Hölder's inequality.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How do you get that $\frac{\partial u_{k}}{\partial x}$ also converges in $L^{2}$?

Comment: @John I overlooked the symbol of weak convergence at first. Edited. Those derivatives converge weakly, because they come from a weakly convergent sequence in a Sobolev space.

Comment: So you are saying that $u_{k} \rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ implies $\frac{\partial u_{k}}{\partial x} \rightharpoonup \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ in $L^{2}(\Omega)$. Can you give me an idea or hint as to how you would show this? Thanks.

Comment: @John Differentiation is a bounded linear operator from $W^{1,2}$ to $L^2$, so it carries weakly convergent sequences into weakly convergent sequences.